# Formdata post with vuex

Tags: forms, vue.js, post, vuex, vue-router

I am very new to vuex and vue-js. I am trying to post my forms data using vuex. So far I managed to pass the Title successfully but I don’t know how to pass more than one piece of data?

data to pass:

```
// Title
<input type="text" name="subject_title">`

// selected data
<datepicker id="set_date" name="set_date"></datepicker> 

// array of options
<multiselect v-model="value" :max-height="0" :options="options" :searchable="false" :multiple="true" group-label="language" track-by="name" label="name" placeholder=""><span class="arrow" slot="caret"></span></multiselect>
```

---

I have put some of my code on github: https://github.com/samB67/VuexPost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a object to store your whole form in your  file `upload.vue`;

```
data() {
//...
  homeworkForm: {
    title: '',
    date: null,
    somethingElse: ''

  }
}
```

Now in your form, you simply put the v-model to bind to each corresponding keys from your homeworkForm object;

```
<input v-model="homeworkForm.title" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Enter text">
<!-- ... -->
<datepicker v-model="homeworkForm.date" id="set_date" name="set_date" />
```

Then when you want to submit the form, you send the whole homeworkForm object to vuex.

```
postHandler() {
  this.$store.dispatch('createHomework', this.homeworkForm);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I have just created a test and it worked!